# Create a simple quiz for each video

Tags: 7, forms, quiz

I have a "video" content type, and I want from users watching my videos to answer some questions related to each single video.

Can you advice me, how can I create a quiz for each single video content ?
Is there a module (I tried the [quiz](https://drupal.org/project/quiz) module but it's very complicated) to do that, or any other way will be apprecited.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use the simple `comment` module?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module to create a quiz.

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Webform is the module for making surveys in Drupal. After a submission, users may be sent an e-mail "receipt" as well as sending a notification to administrators. Results can be exported into Excel or other spreadsheet applications. Webform also provides some basic statistical review and has and extensive API for expanding its features.
>
> Some good examples could be contests, personalized contact forms, or petitions. Each of these could have a customized form for end-users to fill out. If you need to build a lot of customized, one-off forms, Webform is a more suitable solution than creating content types and using CCK or Field module.

Comment: How can I attach the created form with a specific node ?

Comment: create a views block and filter the webform, to attach the webform you can use views_embed_views or https://drupal.org/project/views_field you can add views field in your video content type

Comment: This is a Q+A site, not a forum.  Please add further explanations about how to your answer to the body by clicking the "Edit" button below your answer.

Comment: download the module and enabled it, then add new field views field and configured it base on your needs.